# Show that if $x \not\equiv23 \pmod{101}$, then $x^{33} \not\equiv9 \pmod{101}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can I have help to prove that for all integers $x$, if $x \not\equiv23 \pmod{101}$, then $x^{33} \not\equiv9 \pmod{101}$?

First I start with contrapositive, but how I can work with it? I try splitting the modulus, but it is prime. Can someone help please? Thanks.

Comment: Well, there can't be two such $x\pmod {101}$ since there can be no solution to $n^{33}\equiv 1 \pmod {101}$ other than $1$.

Comment: I agree with you that the contrapositive is easier to work with. If $x^{33}\equiv9\pmod{101}$, then $x^{-33}\equiv9^{-1}\pmod{101}$; what happens if you cube both sides and apply Fermat's little theorem?

Comment: @GregMartin but if you cube, you get $x^{-99}$, I have to make it $x^{-100}$ to use right?

Comment: after cubing, multiply by $x^{100}\equiv1$, and what do you get?

Comment: The $x \equiv\frac{1}{9^{3}}$? Sorry im abit confused.

Comment: Yes, and what's $9^{-1}\pmod{ 101}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$x(x^{33})^3 \equiv 1 mod (101)$$

$$x^{33}\equiv (r^{1/3}=\frac 1 x^{\frac 13}) mod (101)$$

Due to statement we must have:

$r^{1/3}\neq 9$, or, : $\frac 1x \neq 729 $, or:$x\neq\frac 1{729}$

Now we have $x\neq 23 +101 k$.

That means $x$ may be: $x=101k+22.$

In this case for $k=7$ we get: $x=707+22=729,$ which contradicts the second condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, prove the contrapositive.  Let $x^{33}\equiv9\bmod101$.

Then $x^{-1}\equiv (x^{100})x^{-1}\equiv(x^{33})^3\equiv   9^3=729\equiv22$.

Thus $x\equiv22^{-1}\equiv23\bmod101$.